# Probability that the union of two subsets of X is equal to X

Tags: probability

Let $X = \{1,2,... n \}$. The task is to calculate the probability that for two randomly chosen, **non-empty**, **distinct** sets $A,B \in X$ holds $A \cup B = X$.

I am struggling to find the mistake in my reasoning.

Firstly, the number of ways for choosing two non-empty, distinct subsets of $X$ is
 $$\sum_{k_1=1}^n {n \choose k_1} \cdot [\sum_{k_2=1}^n {n \choose k_2} - 1] = (2^n - 1)(2^n-2)$$

because for every constructed set $A$ that can contain $1, 2, ... n$ elements, there are $\sum_{k_2=1}^n {n \choose k_2}$ ways of constructing the set $B$ that can also contain $1, 2,...n$ elements, **minus the one way of selecting the two exact same sets**.

My idea for calculating the number of ways for constructing $A,B$ such that $A \cup B = X$ went as follows.

Firstly, I divided the problem into two scenarios – $A$ having $1, 2, ... n-1$ elements and $A=X$.

For each constructed $A$ in the first case, there are some elements remaining outside $A$ – atleast one. For every such $A$, I noticed I could construct $B$ by selecting an arbitrary subset of $A$ (empty set is also an option) and **adding to it those remaining elements.** The number of ways for constructing $B$ is then equal to the number of subsets.

In the second scenario, if $A=X$, $B$ can be any non-empty subset of $A$.
This boils down to:

$$\sum_{k_1=1}^{n-1} {n \choose k_1} \cdot [\sum_{k_2=0}^{k_1} {{k_1 \choose k_2} \cdot {{n-k_1}\choose{n-k_1}}}] + {n \choose n}\cdot {\sum_{k_2=1}^{n-1}{n \choose k_2}} = 3^n - 3$$

The final result is:
$$P(A \cup B = x) = \frac{3^n - 3}{(2^n - 1)(2^n-2)}$$

which is **not** the textbook solution. The authors approached the problem from a different angle and I wanted to see where did I go wrong. The correct result is $P(A \cup B = X) = \frac{3^n - 2^{n+1} + 1}{(2^n - 1)(2^n-2)}$

Comment: So *distinct* means non-identical rather than non-intersecting?

Comment: @Henry distinct as in non-identical. Did I use the wrong term?

Comment: If you explain, then it is not a problem, but I was initially confused

Comment: You can get proper brackets that adjust to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`, respectively.

Comment: What is the $\binom{n-k_1}{n-k_1}$ accomplishing for you?

Comment: @CameronBuie it is here for the sake of clarifying what I meant by _adding the remaining elements to every chosen subset of A_ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you

For your first scenario there are $k_1$ elements of $A$, in which case there are ${n \choose k_1}$ ways of selecting $A$ and there are then $2^{k_1}{n-k_1 \choose n-k_1}=2^{k_1}$ ways of choosing a satisfactory $B$

So the first scenario leads to $\sum\limits_{k_1=1}^{n-1} {n \choose {k_1}}2^{k_1} =  \sum\limits_{k_1=0}^{n} {n \choose {k_1}}2^{k_1} -2^n-1=3^n-2^n-1$ possibilities which I think is the same as your result

Then add the second scenario's $2^n-2$ (all except nothing or everything) and you get your $3^n-3$

Meanwhile *subtracting* the $2^n-2$ and you would get the textbook's $3^n-2^{n+1}+1$

Comment: I agree with Henry. The textbook answer is correct if (in addition to the empty set) the whole set X is disallowed as one of the subsets. Perhaps somebody forgot to state that restriction. If X is allowed as one of the subsets, then the OP's answer is correct.

Comment: The first part of the example was to calculate the probability of two subsets being disjunct. The task I described above was solved using the first part. If the union of A and B is X, that means that the intersection of their complements is an empty set, which boils down to the first problem. If the set cannot be empty, it's complement cannot be X. You're right - but I am glad to hear my reasoning was good.